# Angular can't find the variable: data

Tags: angularjs

I've already done with my first angular app. I have an error while calling a function.
Here is a snippet of my JSON:

```
{

  "variantA": {
    "sumInsuredThirty": [
      {
        "dayFrom": 1,
        "dayTo": 3,
        "tarif": 2
      }, ...
```

I've got it via:

```
  $http.get("/CalculatorMed/JSON/rates.json/").then(function(data) {
        $scope.rates = data.data;
        });
```

Now, I'm trying to get the tarif:

```
$scope.getBaseTarif = function () {
        var baseTarif = 0;
        if (data.pickedOptions.variantA === true && data.pickedOptions.sumInsured === 30000) {
            for (var i = 0; i < rates.variantA.sumInsuredThirty.lenght; i++) {
                if (data.pickedOptions.days >= rates.variantA.sumInsuredThirty[ i ].dayFrom && data.pickedOptions.days <= rates.variantA.sumInsuredThirty[ i ].dayTo) {
                    baseTarif = rates.variantA.sumInsuredThirty[ i ].tarif;
                    return baseTarif;
                }
            }
        }
      };
```

And I have an error:

Error: Can't find variable: data
getBaseTarif@http://localhost:63342/CalculatorMed/controller/calculator.js:34:17
fn

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: As your error says: **What is data?** Shouldn't it be `$scope.rates`?

Comment: .length spelling not correct

Comment: also its should be $scope.rates = data;

Comment: Which line threw this error?

Comment: @MMK, In this way the code works fine. I can call any item within {{}} ..

Comment: @P.Shustenko Great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data cannot be access outside, it should be $scope.rates,

```
 if ($scope.rates.pickedOptions.variantA === true && $scope.rates.pickedOptions.sumInsured === 30000) {
            for (var i = 0; i < rates.variantA.sumInsuredThirty.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.rates.pickedOptions.days >= rates.variantA.sumInsuredThirty[i].dayFrom && $scope.rates.pickedOptions.days <= rates.variantA.sumInsuredThirty[i].dayTo) {
                    baseTarif = rates.variantA.sumInsuredThirty[i].tarif;
                    return baseTarif;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Who's the down voter? This is a correct answer I thought. Down voter, please put your reason here to improve the answer.

Comment: @Sajeetharan, Thank you! I'm learning JS/AngularJS by myself ... The error has gone, but my function has'n returned the needed item ..

Comment: @P.Shustenko you might have to debug and check